# Setting up mod_jk redirect in Hybris

Tags: apache, tomcat, port, sap-commerce-cloud, mod-jk

I have installed apache httpd 2.2.15 in my app server. I need to get the login page(https://ip_address:9002/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/login) when I hit on https://dev.xxyy.com/login. I have installed SSL certificate for my domain and set below redirect rules.

```
ProxyPass         /login http://localhost:9001/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/login
ProxyPassReverse  /login http://localhost:9001/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/login
ProxyPass         /login https://localhost:9002/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/login
ProxyPassReverse  /login https://localhost:9002/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/login

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/login http://%{ip_address:9001}$1/{xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/login}$2 [L,R]
```

When I hit on https://dev.xxyy.com/login, I get below error,

```
Not Found 
The requested URL /login was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at dev.xxyy.com Port 443
```

When I hit on https://dev.xxyy.com, I get the apache default homepage.

Pls guide me how should I set the redirect rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is invalid. Those two lines:

```
ProxyPass         /login https://localhost:9002/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/login
ProxyPassReverse  /login https://localhost:9002/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/login
```

overwrite those two:

```
ProxyPass         /login http://localhost:9001/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/login
ProxyPassReverse  /login http://localhost:9001/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/login
```

Rewite mechanism probably does not work at all:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/login http://%{ip_address:9001}$1/{xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/login}$2 [L,R]
```

I think this configuration should solve your problem:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName        dev.xxyy.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass         / http://localhost:9001/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/
    ProxyPassReverse  / http://localhost:9001/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName        dev.xxyy.com

    SSLEngine on
    // other SSL directives

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass         / https://localhost:9002/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/
    ProxyPassReverse  / https://localhost:9002/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/
</VirtualHost>
```

It defines two virtual hosts which work as proxies and map all requests to `xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/...`:

```
http://dev.xxyy.com/(.*) → http://localhost:9001/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/(.*)
https://dev.xxyy.com/(.*) → https://localhost:9002/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/(.*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped, now I am able to get the redirection working. But the css is not loading for my pages. Do I need to add any more properties in the conf file?

Comment: Got it resolved by changing as

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName        dev.xxyy.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass         / http://localhost:9001/
    ProxyPassReverse  / http://localhost:9001/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName        dev.xxyy.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass         / https://localhost:9002/
    ProxyPassReverse  / https://localhost:9002/
</VirtualHost>

But only when I hit on https://dev.xxyy.com/xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/, I am able to view page. I should get the page on https://dev.xxyy.com. Any suggestions pls

Comment: Where are located your CSS files? Please give me an example URL.

Comment: I have css as below
xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/login
xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/register
xxstorefront/xx/en/USD/logout

Comment: I am able to get login page. But internal redirection not working. Like when I click on register, it shows not found. 
Should I set internal redirect rules? Any suggestions pls.